# Facebook app that gives you the list of IDs of your Facebook friends

Tags: facebook

Each person on Facebook has an ID like "92385284" or "100329233247".

How do I get a list containing the IDs of all my friends?

The "[Download a copy of your Facebook data](https://www.facebook.com/help/131112897028467/)" button generates a `friends.html` files which is nearly that, but it contains the names (like "Robert Smith") instead of the IDs.

*(I am using these IDs to associate with my address book.)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Friend List Exporter](https://apps.facebook.com/friendlistexporter/).

It allow you to download:

> Download a basic textual list of your friends.
>
> Download a basic textual list of your friends with profile links.
>
> Download an html list of your friends with profile links and profile
>   pictures.
>
> Download a spreadsheet (csv) of your friends with ID numbers, profile
>   links, and profile picture links.

(the last option is useful for your case).

It outputs an spreadsheet like:

```
id  name  link              picture
1   bob   facebook.com/bob  fbcdn-profil...
```

You can delete the last 2 columns if necessary.

Note: Excel by default shows numbers like +E10 (or similar), so format the ID column as `number` with `0 decimal places` to show the full number.

Comment: This app does not work anymore, it only returns empty files.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul :( probably because the api now requires you to have users authorize your app before returning the friends list! sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

If you get an access token then the facebook api - see [here](https://developers.facebook.com) - should let you query me/friends to get a list with the required data but you are likely to have to register for an app.

Comment: To register an app, Facebook requires me to provide a cellphone email address, but my carrier does not provide that, so I can't register unfortunately.